# Required HTML template for web application release notes

Tags: html, web-applications

I want to provide a release note for my web application, and I wanted to know that Is there any readymade `HTML` template is available on web ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one from the Apache Software Foundation

https://github.com/apache/incubator-blur/blob/master/docs/release-notes.template.html